# Thread-safe queue with condition variables in C++17

Tags: c++, thread-safety, locking, c++17, condition-variable

I have implemented some example queue-implementation with a simple vector in C++17 and I am not really sure now if this is the optimal way how I have realized it and if it is all 100% race-condition-safe. Maye you can take a critical look at what I have done? I made an example and it seems to be working fine. The inserter-threads should be waiting when  the queue is full and the fetcher-threads should be waiting when the queue is empty.
The threads should not sleep a long time at once, because there is other stuff to do in the meantime. An important future-requirement will be now, that when the queue is full und the inserter-thread is going to sleep, that it will inform some other instance to stop too (function-call of external lib). Is it a save/good practise to implement this trigger in the predicate of waiting_for (`if (!pred) trigger stop; return pred;`)? I need the stop at the point of time when the inserter is going to sleep and a coresponding start when the thread has been woken up.

*Questions In short:*

- Is my actual QueueThreadSafe-implementation ok and safe? What can I do better?
- How and where to implement a stop- and start-trigger in the inserter-thread at the time when the thread is going to sleep/awake because of a full queue?

**QueueThreadSafe**

```
    #pragma once
    
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <vector> 
    
    #include <iostream> 
    
    namespace lib::queue
    {
        template < class T >
        struct QueueThreadSafe
        {
            using queue_type_t = std::vector< T >;
        private:
            queue_type_t _queue;
            uint64_t _queueMaxSize;
            std::mutex _queueMutex;
            std::condition_variable cvFetch;
            std::condition_variable cvInsert;
        public:
            explicit QueueThreadSafe( uint64_t queueMaxSize ) noexcept :
                _queueMaxSize( queueMaxSize )
            {
                _queue.reserve( _queueMaxSize );
            }
            
            template < class T_INSERT >
            auto insert( T_INSERT && item )
            {
                {
                    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _queueMutex );
                    if ( !cvInsert.wait_for( lock, 
                                             std::chrono::seconds( 2 ), 
                                             [ &queue        = _queue, 
                                               &queueMaxSize = _queueMaxSize ]
                                             { return queue.size() <= queueMaxSize; } ) )
                        return false;
    
                    _queue.emplace_back( std::forward< T >( item ) );
                }
    
                cvFetch.notify_all();
                return true;
            }
    
            auto fetchAll( queue_type_t &refFetchedItems )
            {
                 {
                    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _queueMutex );
                    if ( !cvFetch.wait_for( lock, 
                                            std::chrono::seconds( 2 ), 
                                            [ &queue = _queue ]{ return !queue.empty(); } ) )
                        return false;
    
                    refFetchedItems = _queue;
                    _queue.clear();
                }
    
                cvInsert.notify_all();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

**Test-Program:**

```
    #include "queue_thread_safe.h"
    
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    
    namespace 
    {
        auto sleepMs( uint64_t sleepMs) { std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( sleepMs ) ); }
        #define LOG( x ) std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    
    int main() 
    {
        static constexpr uint64_t delay_in_ms_for_insert_one_item  = 1,
                                  delay_in_ms_for_process_one_item = 100,
                                  shared_queue_size                = 10,
                                  shared_queue_insert_count        = 50;
    
        lib::queue::QueueThreadSafe< int > sharedQueue( shared_queue_size );
    
        //Thread 1
        std::thread insertThread( [ &sharedQueue ]()
            {
                for ( auto i=1; i <= shared_queue_insert_count; ++i )
                {
                    sleepMs( delay_in_ms_for_insert_one_item );
                    LOG( "[Thread1] Trying to insert value " << i << " ... " )
                        for( auto queueFree = false; !queueFree; )
                            queueFree = sharedQueue.insert( i );
                    LOG( "[Thread1] -> Successfully inserted value " << i )
                }
            });
    
        //Main-thread
        for ( decltype( sharedQueue )::queue_type_t fetchedItems; 
              fetchedItems.empty() || fetchedItems.back() != shared_queue_insert_count; ) 
        {
            LOG( "[Main   ] Trying to fetch values ... " );
                for( auto queueHasData = false; !queueHasData; )
                    queueHasData = sharedQueue.fetchAll( fetchedItems );
            LOG( "[Main   ] -> Successfully fetched "<< fetchedItems.size() << " values." )
    
            //Working at the items 
            for ( const auto &item : fetchedItems ) 
            {
                LOG( "[Main   ] -> working at value " << item );
                sleepMs( delay_in_ms_for_process_one_item );
            }
        }
    
        if ( insertThread.joinable() )
            insertThread.join();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

***[ Actual adapted version ]***

Adaptions/Fixes:

- Removed unnecessary iostream-include
- Added T_INSERT to std::forward instead of T
- Fixed off-by-one-error when checking queue-limit
- Added move-assignment when fetching the queue

**QueueThreadSafe**

```
    #pragma once
    
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <vector> 
    
    namespace lib::queue
    {
        template < class T >
        struct QueueThreadSafe
        {
            using queue_type_t = std::vector< T >;
        private:
            queue_type_t _queue;
            uint64_t _queueMaxSize;
            std::mutex _queueMutex;
            std::condition_variable cvFetch;
            std::condition_variable cvInsert;
        public:
            explicit QueueThreadSafe( uint64_t queueMaxSize ) noexcept :
                _queueMaxSize( queueMaxSize )
            {
                _queue.reserve( _queueMaxSize );
            }
            
            template < class T_INSERT >
            auto insert( T_INSERT && item )
            {
                {
                    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _queueMutex );
                    if ( !cvInsert.wait_for( lock, 
                                             std::chrono::seconds( 2 ), 
                                             [ &queue        = _queue, 
                                               &queueMaxSize = _queueMaxSize ]
                                             { return queue.size() < queueMaxSize; } ) )
                        return false;
    
                    _queue.emplace_back( std::forward< T_INSERT  >( item ) );
                }
    
                cvFetch.notify_all();
                return true;
            }
    
            auto fetchAll( queue_type_t &refFetchedItems )
            {
                 {
                    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _queueMutex );
                    if ( !cvFetch.wait_for( lock, 
                                            std::chrono::seconds( 2 ), 
                                            [ &queue = _queue ]{ return !queue.empty(); } ) )
                        return false;
    
                    refFetchedItems = std::move ( _queue );
                    _queue.clear();
                }
    
                cvInsert.notify_all();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: `refFetchedItems = std::move(_queue);` would avoid copying the elements.

Comment: The queue may grow one element larger than `queueMaxSize`. The wait condition in `insert` is satisfied when `queue.size() == queueMaxSize`, and then one more element is added on top.

Comment: I don't see any bugs in thread safety but I wouldn't call it a good implementation. You could post in code review for a more detailed analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation is thread-safe because all your queue-related members (_queue and _queueMaxSize) are protected by the mutex.

Anyway, you might end up waiting for data in `fetchAll` (and potentially running into the timeout) even though there are actually items in the queue: Imagine the `fetchAll` just returned and before calling it again a new item is inserted. The `notify_all` on `cvFetch` wouldn't cause any thread to unblock, because no one is waiting on `cvFetch`. Now, when `fetchAll` is called again, there is an item in the queue but wait_for on `cvFetch` won't unblock until another item is inserted. The solution is to check the queue size before calling wait_for on `cvFetch`: if there are currently items in the queue, return them immediately, otherwise call wait_for on `cvFetch`.

Besides that I'd suggest making the timeouts parameters to the constructor.

Regarding the "stop trigger" question: It's not correct to emit the stop trigger from within the predicate of `std::condition_variable::wait_for`, because there is no guarantee that the predicate is ever called if there is no notification (`std::condition_variable::notify_all`). You should rather emit the stop trigger *before* calling `std::condition_variable::wait_for`:

```
        template < class T_INSERT >
        auto insert( T_INSERT && item )
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _queueMutex );
                if(queue.size() == queueMaxSize)
                {
                    // trigger stop
                }
                if ( !cvInsert.wait_for( lock, 
                                         std::chrono::seconds( 2 ), 
                                         [ &queue        = _queue, 
                                           &queueMaxSize = _queueMaxSize ]
                                         { return queue.size() < queueMaxSize; } ) )
                    return false;

                _queue.emplace_back( std::forward< T_INSERT  >( item ) );
                // trigger start
            }

            cvFetch.notify_all();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example? When fetchAll is called again, why would 
it block? The queue has 1 pending item and cvFetch would check the predicate 
before going to sleep?

Comment: I clarified the solution "to check the queue size before calling wait_for on cvFetch" in my answer. Further explanation: when there are items in the queue, fetchAll returns immediately with the popped items. Then your program processes the returned items and will then call fetchAll again. This time the queue is empty and therefore wait_for on cvFetch is called causing fetchAll call to block until new items arrive. Hope that helps. If you need a working example, I'd suggest you create one and I can adapt it.

Comment: "Anyway, you might end up waiting for data in fetchAll (and potentially running into the timeout) even though there are actually items in the queue". This cannot be happen, because all is saved with the same mutex. I cannot reproduce a behavior like this.

Comment: Well, @SoulfreezerXP I took a deeper look into the C++ standard and learned that you are actually right. According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) the predicate is checked immediately when calling `std::condition_variable::wait_for`, so there is no need to check the queue size before calling wait_for on `cvFetch`. Same applies for the stop trigger then, so it's valid to emit the stop trigger from within the predicate. Therefore I agree that my answer has to be downvoted.